# Google authentication version conflict with Google Maps

Tags: android, google-play-services

I was following [the official Google authentication process](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating). My app has been already using the latest version of Google Maps.

project

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.2'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

app

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
....
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'
```

There is a red line under maps and the popup says that it found 11.8.0 and 11.4.2. The build error message is something like,

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
>
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.4.2.

If I comment out `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`, the build error disappears, but the official document tells me to add it.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Your project uses multiple versions of Google libraries. You can find using below command which library use which version

Please run below command on Android terminal ./gradlew -q dependencies app:dependencies --configuration compile

It will show current and latest of libraries which are used in your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following line in the dependencies of the project-level build.gradle:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

For a full working example, check out the [following project](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/signin) on github.

Check [':app:processDebugGoogleServices'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47535863/android-studio-failed-for-task-appprocessdebuggoogleservices) , [Android Studio Gradle: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34679411/android-studio-gradle-errorexecution-failed-for-task-appprocessdebuggoogles)

Hope this may help you.